# Django - Grouping data and showing the foreignkey's name in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

I am trying to create a pie chart (`chart.js`). My goal is grouping departments and displaying how many people work by departments in piechart.

**Models.py**

```py
class Personel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    department = models.ForeignKey(DepartmentList, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=0, related_name="PersonelDepartman")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name},{self.surName}"

    class Meta:
        db_table = "personel"
        verbose_name_plural = "Ar-Ge Personeller"

class DepartmentList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "DepartmentList"
        verbose_name_plural = "Departman Listesi"
```

**Views.py**

```py
def index(request):
    personel_dep = Personel.objects.values('department').annotate(Count('department'))
    context = {
        "personel_dep" : personel_dep,
    }
    return render(request, 'core/index.html',context)
```

```py
>>> print(personel_dep)

>>> <QuerySet [{'department': 1, 'department__count': 5}, {'department': 2, 'department__count': 5}, {'department': 3, 'department__count': 3}, {'department': 4, 'department__count': 3}, {'department': 5, 'department__count': 3}, {'department': 6, 'department__count': 4}, {'department': 7, 'department__count': 1}]>
```

It is okay for me and all i need is in here. But I coulnd't figure out how i can display department's name in my template(also in chart label)

**Template**

```
{% for dep in personel_dep %}<p>{{ dep.department }}</p>{% endfor %}
```

if i use; `personel_dep = Personel.objects.filter(rdfinisDate__isnull=True)`

i can reach the names in template as `{% for dep in personel_respons %}<p>{{ dep.get_respons_display }}</p>{% endfor %}`

What am I missing? I thin `.values` is problem for my issue. In these case is there any way to display department name or easy way to display name of departments in chart label?

Comment: Can you try ```Personel.objects.values('department', 'department__name').annotate(Count('department'))``` ? You should be able to access it in your template with dep.department__name.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You are right.

Comment: I wrote it as an answer. Do you mind validating it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view, you can query foreign keys like that:

```py
def index(request):
    personel_dep = Personel.objects.values('department', 'department__name').annotate(Count('department'))
    context = {
        "personel_dep" : personel_dep,
    }
    return render(request, 'core/index.html',context)
```

And then, in your templates, you can access it via:

```
{% for dep in personel_dep %}
    <p>{{dep.department__name}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```